# One function causes irregular behaviour of another function afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

So I have created a search bar with a filter function that will open when you click the filter icon. However, while testing it out I discovered a bug. For some reason, if you click 'clear all filters', you will need to click an item on a list twice (instead of once--as it was intended to be) before it will change its background colour once again. Furthermore, if you click an item twice to highlight it again, and then unhighlight it, it will only require one click to highlight it once again as usual.

[Here is a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fjemwab1/4/)

I thought it might have had something to do with not specifying the background colour in the condition of the following if else statement

```
function highlightSelections() {
    if (this.style.background === '') {
        this.style.background = '#f7931a';
    } else {
        console.log(this.style.background);
        this.style.background = '';
    };
};
```

Yet for whatever reason specifying `this.style.background === 'rgb(227, 226, 224)'` in the JS and `.options { background: rgb(227, 226, 224); }` CSS breaks it to a much greater degree.

In the following code the first `console.log(this.style.background)` logs a blank line, even though I have explicitly set the background color in CSS.

```
function highlightSelections() {
    if (this.style.background === 'rgb(227, 226, 224)') {
        console.log(this.style.background);
        this.style.background = '#f7931a';
    } else {
        console.log(this.style.background);
        this.style.background = 'rgb(227, 226, 224)';
    };
};
```

Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is (or was) the culprit:

```
clearIcon.addEventListener('click', clearAllFilters);
function clearAllFilters() {
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < filterOptionsClass.length; i++) {
        filterOptionsClass[i].style.background = 'rgb(227, 226, 224)';
    };
    currencyOption.style.background = 'rgb(227, 226, 224)';
    regionOption.style.background   = 'rgb(227, 226, 224)';
    industryOption.style.background = 'rgb(227, 226, 224)';
    reviewOption.style.background   = 'rgb(227, 226, 224)';
    filterContainer.innerHTML = '';
    toggleClearIcon();
};
```

And the following code works like a charm:

```
clearIcon.addEventListener('click', clearAllFilters);
function clearAllFilters() {
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < filterOptionsClass.length; i++) {
        filterOptionsClass[i].style.background = '';
    };
    currencyOption.style.background = '';
    regionOption.style.background   = '';
    industryOption.style.background = '';
    reviewOption.style.background   = '';
    filterContainer.innerHTML = '';
    toggleClearIcon();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because whenever you cleared your list,you set the style background on each 'filter-option' to clear it out...this is problematic.

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/calbear47/4odgw60b/)

Change your clearAllFilters to this, and you should be good to go.

```
 function clearAllFilters() {
  while (selectedFilters.length > 0) {
      selectedFilters.pop();
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < filterOptionsClass.length; i++) {
      filterOptionsClass[i].removeAttribute("style");
  };
  filterContainer.innerHTML = '';
  toggleClearIcon();
};
```

Comment: i just actually figured it out. it had nothing to do with that. i'm going to add it as an answer below if you're interested

Comment: My solution is exactly what yours was, except that I'm actually removing the style attribute instead  of setting it to an empty string, where as your code is redundant. :-)

Comment: you obviously didn't look at the code too thoroughly if at all